# CUBIN: CUDA_ERROR_NO_BINARY_FOR_GPU error while running Attention Layer with Bidirectional LSTM in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am using a self-defined attention layer to add to my Bidirectional LSTM model.

```
import keras
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Layer, Input, Bidirectional, LSTM, Dense, Attention

class attention(Layer):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(attention,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self,input_shape):
        self.W=self.add_weight(name="att_weight",shape=(input_shape[-1],1),initializer="normal")
        self.b=self.add_weight(name="att_bias",shape=(input_shape[1],1),initializer="zeros")        
        super(attention, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self,x):
        et=K.squeeze(K.tanh(K.dot(x,self.W)+self.b),axis=-1)
        at=K.softmax(et)
        at=K.expand_dims(at,axis=-1)
        output=x*at
        return K.sum(output,axis=1)

    def compute_output_shape(self,input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0],input_shape[-1])

    def get_config(self):
        return super(attention,self).get_config()
```

Model defined as

```
inputs = Input(shape=(1, len(features)))
att_in = Bidirectional(LSTM(16, return_sequences= True, dropout=0.2))(inputs)
att_out = attention()(att_in)
# l2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))(att_out)
d1 = Dense(8, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(att_out)
outputs = Dense(1, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(d1)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
             loss = 'mse',
             metrics = ['mse'])

history = model.fit(x_train[:100], y_train[:100], epochs = 1000, batch_size = 5, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), shuffle=False)
```

Error I get while I execute `model.fit`

```
InternalError:  Failed to load in-memory CUBIN: CUDA_ERROR_NO_BINARY_FOR_GPU: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
     [[node model/attention/Tanh (defined at tmp/ipykernel_30186/2175341019.py:16) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5003]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I am using Keras 2.4.3, with TensorFlow 2.4.1 on NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 computeCapability: 8.6 with CUDA 12.0

I tried using a smaller data set (only 100 data points) along with a smaller batch size (of 5) to get my memory consumption in check but still, I am seeing almost all of the GPU memory being utilized and then generating the above error before training starts. Is there a memory leak or some other issue I am missing out on? Any help is hugely appreciated.

Update: If I change `tanh` activation to `sigmoid` in `self.call` it works.
What is causing it to not work with `tanh` activation is the remaining question.

Comment: You probably need a newer version of TensorFlow, latest GPUs cannot be used with older versions, so try something like TF 2.9 or 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

The build configuration of TensorFlow with GPU setup is not correct in your system.
You need to install `cuDNN 8.0` and `CUDA 11.0` for the `TensorFlow version 2.4` with the `python` version `(3.6 - 3.8)`.

Please check the image below:[image]

**Note:** You can also try by upgrading the tensorflow to the latest version along with installing the compatible version of all the required softwares for enabling GPU support. Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) for the reference.